# What are the differences in the remastered Children of the Gods?

Tags: alternate-version, stargate, stargate-sg1

The first episode of Stargate SG1 was called "[Children of the Gods](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0234794/)", this was a two part special to introduce the series and set up the team [which was later remastered into a "Final Cut"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1483803/).

In an interview with executive producer Brad Wright, he said:

> "There is new material, but most of the new material is visual effects or scenes that have been cut. It is tighter. It is significantly tighter. ... The editing pattern is different, and therefore the performances are different. It's a different movie."

I haven't found a definitive list of changes but from further reading (for example, the section regarding the Goa'uld Tel'tak on [Wikipedia's list of starships in Stargate article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_starships_in_Stargate), which indicates that the Tel'tek was first introduced in the season 3 episode Deadman Switch but later added to the final cut of Children of the Gods) I am under the impression that maybe Brad was playing down some of the changes a bit?

What are the differences in the remastered Children of the Gods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to find [this](http://www.gateworld.net/news/2009/07/review-stargate-sg-1-children-of-the-gods-final-cut/) article. It's quite a big one and I think it has answers to your question.

**A summary of what has changed:**

- Carter's introduction is smoother. The line about reproductive organs is gone.
- Closer relationship between Kawalsky and O'Neill. The question about Jack's kid was removed.
- Apophis' harem scene is gone. And Sha're is abducted after the Earth officer is dismissed as a new host.
- No nudity.
- The scene where Kawalsky is infected by a Goa'uld was deleted to give a positive ending to the episode.
- A scene was added were Apophis gives an order to redial the gate manually.
- Dialogs in some scenes were rerecorded.
- Teal'c's turn on Apophis is more natural, because they've added shots of him witnessing horrors perpetrated by Apophis.
- Changes in visual effects: stargate puddle, sunrise over Chulak, Abydonian pyramid, the near end battle sequence

Comment: They also added a few deleted scenes back in (e.g. Jack inviting Daniel to his house), replaced the never-seen-again ship that Apophis escapes in with a cargo ship, and had Christopher Judge redub all his lines as Teal'c. (He was still experimenting with his voice and was freezing on set since he was unaccustomed to not having hair; I think he sounds "Jamaican" in the original version).